# Optimize if tree in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have an "if decision tree" and I want to know if it's possible to optimize it:

```
    def s(a, b):
    """
    :param a: 0,1,2
    :param b: 0,1,2
    :return: 0,1,2
    """
    if a == 0:
        if b == 0:
            return 2
        elif b == 1:
            return 2
        else:  # b == 2
            return 0
    elif a == 1:
        if b == 0:
            return 2
        elif b == 1:
            return 2
        else:  # b == 2
            return 1
    else:  # a==2
        if b == 0:
            return 0
        elif b == 1:
            return 1
        else:  # b==2
            return 2
```

All cases included, I'm trying use (a,b) == (1,2) or (a,b) == (2,1) return 1
and the same when return 0. Other cases return 2, but it is slower.

EDIT:
I have tested (time and valid (all valid)) all proposed "ifs" and:
s is my explicit function
ss is first proposed function
sss is second proposed function
etc.
and here I have profile:
[image: profile all functions]

Comment: Yes, it is possible to optimize.

Comment: You could optimize using `and` and `or` but if you're concerned about optimizing an if-statement, you're usually over thinking optimization

Comment: @cricket_007 I disagree. If the logic is really as simple as OP wrote in the last sentence, you should be able to represent *exactly* that logic. Writing out all possible cases is not a good way to get the logic across. And it’s very error prone, since I would have to look many times to verify that the cases are really all correct.

Comment: I wrote it this way only because I need to check if all possibilities return valid value. Then decide to ask stack community :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check those values explicitely by comparing the tuples, and return `2` in all other cases:

```
v = (a, b)
if v == (1, 2) or v == (2, 1):
    return 1
elif v == (0, 2) or v == (2, 0):
    return 0
else:
    return 2
```

You could even go a bit further and think about what your check does: If any of the numbers is two, you return the other number.

```
if a == 2:
    return b
elif b == 2:
    return a
else:
    return 2
```

In general, of course you could also create an exact mapping, e.g. using a dictionary, that allows you to look up the result directly (instead of having a complex if/else structure). But when your logic to determine the result really fits in a single sentence, then you should really try to implement it in a way that keeps that concise logic intact. Otherwise, it would be very difficult to spot errors (for example, it took me a while to verify that your if/else code really does what you said it would). Of course, you can always use those different possible combinations in a unit test to make sure that your logic actually covers it all.

Comment: your second function is a little faster than explicit all if statement

Answer (score 2):

If you know you're not going to get a=3 or b=-1, here's a oneliner:

```
def new_s(a,b):
    return min(a,b) if max(a,b) == 2 else 2
```

Comment: this is the slowest function

Comment: If you're talking about optimizing from a speed perspective, then you're better off doing something with numpy, Cython, or similar tools rather than pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a dictionary.

```
mydict[0][0] = 2
mydict[0][1] = 2
mydict[0][2] = 0
mydict[1][0] = 2
mydict[1][1] = 2
mydict[1][2] = 1
mydict[2][0] = 0
mydict[2][1] = 1
mydict[2][2] = 2

print mydict[a][b]
```

How to create dict of dict:

```
mydict = dict()
mydict[0] = dict()
mydict[0][1] = 2
```

Comment: How to make two integer key dictionary? It's dict of dicts? I use tuple keys but I'm not sure if that is appropriate

Comment: Yes, that is dict of dict. Added a sample to the code.

Comment: @Behoston You can use tuple keys too, that’s fine.